# how to pass data from multiple button to 1 jquery

Tags: jquery

first, i have multiple dynamic buttons which generate by php. example:

```
<button id='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber5' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
<button id='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber50' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
<button id='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber15' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
<button id='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber35' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
```

now i need to pass/get value to jquery when i calling jquery

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   var tit=("$btn").attr("title");
   var val=("$btn").attr("value");
   alert(tit +":"+ val);
});
```

my problem is, it only function for the 1st button, others did not function.
i know my code is have problem but how should i write, so that i can have multiple dynamic button but calling/using 1 jquery script and it can receive data from that button.

by the way, i did search on google and here but i could not find and refer, may be i dont know what is the right keyword to search.

Ps: if possible i wish to put the jquery into function and save to a js.file
anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: Don't forget to click the tick next to the answer that helped you most. That's the way to say "thank you" on Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 3):

`id` values must be unique in a document. Because of that, jQuery only returns the first element with that `id`. Change the `id` attribute to a `class` attribute, and modify your selector:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
   var tit = this.title;
   var val = this.value;
   alert(tit +":"+ val);
});
```

Also notice the changes to the callback function. What you had wasn't going to work (you'd missed the `$` to actually call jQuery) and if you had fixed that mistake, the selectors don't make sense. You can use `this` to refer to the element that has been clicked.

Comment: thanks james, after i follow your suggestion using class, others button is working but it receiving 1st button value and title. As i say each button will having different value which i need to know which button is clicking.

Comment: @user1493339 - Have you changed your callback function to the code in my answer? You need to use `this` to refer to the button that was actually clicked.

Comment: sorry i did not change that, ok you are right, everything work accordingly. it would be nice if i can move the jquery code to another file in function. sorry i new in jquery, just finish the tutorial/sample from w3school 2 days ago.

Comment: It shouldn't need to go in a function (it just needs to go in a DOM ready callback). You can move it to another file no problem. Just make sure that file is included on the page with your buttons.

Comment: james, i'm not sure this can be done or not. is that possible....
1). html button values pass to jquery
2). jquery receive it and pass to ajax
3). ajax get it and pass to php
4). php get it and perform mysql query then return message
5). returned message and show with jquery.append

Comment: @user1493339 - That is definitely possible! I would recommend reading some tutorials or books about JavaScript and AJAX and then trying to write the code. If you get stuck, ask a new question on Stack Overflow and you should be able to get some help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use class instead of id. Id elements are unique in the entire DOM.

```
<button class='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber5' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
<button class='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber50' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
<button class='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber15' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
<button class='btn' type='submit' name='btn' value='recordnumber35' title='deletefromtableA'>delete</button>
```

And the appropriate javascript

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    var tit=this.title;
    var val=this.value;
    alert(tit +":"+ val);
});
```

Comment: ok, thanks, your solution is same as james, is good to have help from you guys.

Comment: @user1493339 - Notice that the code is slightly different here. It passes `this` to jQuery and uses the `attr` method. That will still work, but it will be more efficient to use the native DOM properties e.g. `this.value`, as is done in my answer.

Comment: as i say, i'm new with jquery, i did not notice that slightly different about that. thanks again.